# sqlite max value from a query on two column

Tags: android, sqlite, select, group-by, inner-join

I have a table like this in sqlite:

```
 ********************
 * num *    date    *
 ******************** 
 * 3   * 15-02-2018 *
 * 2   * 15-02-2018 *
 * 6   * 14-02-2018 *
 * 24  * 12-02-2018 *
 * 8   * 15-02-2018 *
 ********************
```

now...i have to get the max row from table respect to (first)date and then num...so in the example the query should return  "8" "15-02-2018" I've tried for 8 hour but without result....my query is:

```
        SELECT t2.num, t2.date
        from
            (
        select(num),max(date) as date
                    from myTable
                    group by num
            ) t1

        inner join myTable t2 on t2.num = t1.num
        and
        t2.date = t1.date
        group by t2.num,t2.date
        limit 1
```

but this query return "2" "15-02-2018"....
Any help is very appreciated !
Alex

Comment: Wrong [date format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). And LIMIT makes no sense without ORDER BY.

Comment: aaargghh...this is format for Italian style.....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will provide the desired result :-

```
SELECT max(num) AS num, date
FROM mytable
GROUP BY substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2)
ORDER BY substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Note `GROUP BY date` would also work.

i.e. :-

[image]

This orders according to an acceptable/recognisable date, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` (*as per [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)*) in descending order, so the latest date is first and only row that is returned as per `LIMIT 1`. It `GROUP`'s according to date (grouping by number basically as no affect as all numbers are unique) thus the maximum number is per date.

Comment: @Magobin, if this answers the question please tick it as answered.